# Rocker switch replacement

Tags: switches

I am trying to replace a rocker switch in an aquarium hood. The original switch has a rating of 4A 125vac. I am having a hard time finding this exact switch. Is it acceptable to replace with a 6a 125vac?

**update:**
Thanks for the responses. There are two ballasts and two small cooling fans being operated by the switch.

Answer (score 2):

Yes.

- The switch needs to be rated at least for the voltage being switched, 125 V. PASS.
- The switch needs to be rated at least for the current being switched, 4 A. Replacement is capable of 6 A. PASS.

Comment: This is a pass transistor answer!!

Answer (score 0):

Yes that should be no problem- assuming the switch is switching just lights and not pumps or chilling compressors. Look for relevant safety agency markings for your jurisdiction (like CSA, UL, TÜV etc.) to be safer.